# How to quantify the ridgeline of an ordinal confusion matrix?

Tags: ordinal-data

We are trying to provide guidance for some folks who want to bring in machine learning tools with multiple classes. They are required to validate the machine's performance, and we are required to provide them the criteria the validation must meet. My simpleton thought would be to count the diagonal as index 0, the next diagonal on each slope as index 1, and so forth. There would then be 3 slopes: the diagonal slope, the south slope, and the north slope. You can walk north or east down the north slope, or west or south down the south slope.

I know that these are typically presented in papers sort of "without comment" because the stats aren't great. But surely there is some way to say "steep slope good. Shallow slopes and daughter ridges bad."

I'm obviously not a statistician. Any recommendations would be most welcome.

[image: Sample confusion matrix of prostate cancer grade groups]

Comment: Are you just suggesting to use a loss function that has loss 0 if the method gets it right, 1 if it gets it wrong by one category, and generally $k$ if it's wrong by $k$ categories? I could understand this more easily without the talk about slopes, but maybe I'm misunderstanding you?

Comment: Loss function. That sounds like a good plan, yes. So the loss in this case would presumably be 56 and that would out of 600 cases, 720 if we include the benign group. In either case, the loss would be less than 10% of the total. Correct?

Comment: Not sure whether "percent of the total" is very meaningful. Anyway, that's a straightforward loss function for such a problem, even though it would treat ordinal data as if the difference between any two categories were the same, which some say shouldn't be done. It will be hard to find something that is clearly better though.

Comment: I'm with your 56 by the way.